# Write a function without using any semicolon

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a very strange problem in my homework.
So I have to build a function which calculates the sum/difference of two numbers.

It looks fairly easy but there's a catch.

This is the function:

```
void sumdif()
{
int result = 0;
//input
//output
}
```

I can't use any semicolons, and this is how the function must look.

Input consists of:
number, + or - (depending if you want to substract or to add) and another number.

The function will output the result.

If I could use semi-colons, it would've been easy.
I have no idea how to resolve this problem in this case, though.

I've thought about using a ternary operator. Unfortunately, I can't see how to take input, output and also differentiate + and - in one line. (and I think I needed ";" anyway so it wouldn't help me).

Here's the problem:
https://www.pbinfo.ro/?pagina=probleme&id=3191

Unfortunately, it is in romanian. You can use google translate for more details, but I've explained the idea.

Through that function you take input, then output the result, and more than that you can't use any semicolon. (this is the hardest part for me - I've never dealt with this before)

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Pretty interesting puzzle. I wonder if there is anything valuable that can be learned from it though.

Comment: "*Input consists of [...] The function will output [...]*" Neither of these facts are reflected in your function header: `void sumdif()`. Maybe start there?

Comment: A similar question was asked on the cplusplus.com forum a decade ago: [only one semicolon!!!](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/9061/). Also see [Write C++ without Semicolons!](http://fusharblog.com/write-cpp-without-semicolons/)

Comment: @scohe001 I have to use that function header. I can't edit it.

Comment: @eerorika I also find it very interesting, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It seems helpful, but I still don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Would codegolf.stackexchange be a better place for this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just performs the operations inside the `if` condition like in the following:

```
void sumdif()
{
    if (char c = '+') { //declare c
        if (cin >> c) { //read c
            if (int a = 1) { //declare a
                if (cin >> a) { //read a
                    if (int b = 1) { //declare b
                        if (cin >> b) { //read b
                            if (c == '+') { //choose operation
                                if (cout << (a + b)) { //print sum
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if (cout << (a - b)) { //print difference
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://wandbox.org/)

Comment: I can't edit the parameters. :( I have to use that specific function, and only add content to it.

Comment: @JohnSmith you can also declare variable inside the if. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. It seems to work as expected.